# Codebehind is adding an undesireable <span> tag to html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using a code behind file to generate a Bootstrap Accordion with some data pulled from a SQL statement.

The Accordion isn't defaulting all closed, but if I click each header, then they close and open as they should. Looking at the generated source, I can see the codebehind is adding an undesirable `<span>` tag which I think could be part of the issue.

Partial Codebehind (This is where I start building thing the `<div>` )

```
lblGenericFundBuild.Text = "<div class=\"panel-group\" id=\"accordion\">";
foreach (DataRow PortfolioLineUpDetail in PortfolioLineUp.Rows) {
    lblGenericFundBuild.Text += "<div class=\"panel panel-info\">";
  lblGenericFundBuild.Text += "<div class=\"panel-heading\">";
   lblGenericFundBuild.Text += "<h4 class=\"panel-title\">";
   lblGenericFundBuild.Text += "<a data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#accordion\" href=\"#collapse" + idDiv.ToString() + "\">" + PortfolioLineUpDetail.Field<Double>("AllocationPercent").ToString() + "%  -  " + PortfolioLineUpDetail.Field<String>("AssetClassName") + "</a>";
lblGenericFundBuild.Text += "</h4>";
lblGenericFundBuild.Text += "</div>";
```

The generated source screenshot. You can see the span take with an id of my asp:Content name and the name of the label.

[image: You can see the span]

How do I stop this from happening!?

Comment: Note that you really shouldn't be adding all of that HTML as a string from the code behind in the first place.  All of that code should just be in the markup from the start.

Comment: How would you recommend adding repeating div pattern where there has to be a lot of logic going on in the background?

Comment: You use a `Repeater`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A server control `asp:Label` will always add a `<span>` tag.

If you do not want that, use the `asp:Literal` control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PlaceHolder` instead of `Label` to have an ASP control that doesn't actually add its own element to the page, but can add child elements on the server.